# execute perforce commands through python

Tags: python, perforce

I am writing a simple script which will sync one perforce directory through python however I am not able to do so.
It is not allowing me to execute anything in that [perforce] directory through script. 
         Can someone please suggest me how I can run commands like p4 login,p4 sync in that directory?

Comment: Are these external commands?  Have you looked at the excellent `subprocess` module?

Comment: I want to execute these commands in perforce folder.. These commands are perforce commands..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what `perforce` is.  Are perforce commands regular executables that live somewhere on your path?  As far as executing them in a particular directory, you can always use `os.chdir` to change to the "perforce" directory...

Comment: ohh no problem.. perforce is a software Configuration management tool

Comment: To better help you, may I kindly ask you to provide some additional info on "It is not allowing me to execute anything in that [perforce] directory through script"? do you receive an error message? may you show us the script you're working on? So far it may be also a permission problem

Answer (score 4):

There is an officially supported [python API for perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html).

You should use that instead of `subprocess` because it allows you to treat a p4 connection as an object and manipulate it using the API instead of manually parsing the output of the p4 command.

Answer (score 3):

Running "p4 sync" without any other arguments will sync the files mapped to the current directory by the current client workspace. When running the command from a Python script you'll need to be aware of where the scrip is actually running.

For debugging purposes, try running "p4 info" first: it'll show what the current working directory is, as well as showing you the rest of your Perforce environment details.

If you always want the script to sync the same directory, no matter where you run it, you might want to consider specifying a path to sync. For example:

- Depot syntax: p4 sync //depot/path/to/dir/...
- Local syntax (Windows): p4 sync c:\users\user\path\to\dir...
- Local syntax (*nix): p4 sync /home/user/path/to/dir/...

If you're client workspace, user or perforce server configuration is configured on a directory basis by P4CONFIG or being set by P4V, you may want to add the global options for these settings to the command as global options. For example:

- p4 -p server:1666 -c client_ws -u user sync //depot/path/to/dir/...

As you're running the commands from Python, you might find that the P4Python scripting API makes the configuration easier: 
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.programming.html

Answer (score 2):

If P4Python is more than you want to deal with there is a Python class in the Perforce Workshop that provides that wraps the command line with the P4Python interface.

[P4Python-esque CLI wrapper for Python](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/lester_cheung/p4util/p4util/p4cli.py)

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success running Perforce commands from Python, using the ActiveState Python 2.7, with the P4Python plugin.  You will need a p4 definition line, like the following:

```
p4Params = {'Port': "perforce_server_name:1666", \
            'Pass': "mypassword", \
            'User': "myname", \
            'Client': "myclient"}
```

Plus you'll need the P4 and P4Exception libraries:

```
from P4 import P4,P4Exception
```

With that in hand, you can perform most any Perforce command with the following construct.  This function syncs to Rev #0 to remove all controlled files from some depot location "depotPath":

```
  def removeWorkFiles(depotPath,p4Params):
  """Tell Perforce to remove the version files from the workspace"""
    p4 = P4(client=p4Params['Client'], port=p4Params['Port'], password=p4Params['Pass'])
    p4.user = p4Params['perfUser']  
    try:
      p4.connect()                 # Connect to the Perforce Server
      p4.run_login()
      deletePath = depotPath + "#0"
      p4.run("sync", "-f", deletePath) # force to version "0", ie remove from workspace
      p4.disconnect()
    except P4Exception:
      for e in p4.errors:          # Display errors
        logging.error( e)
```

I highly recommend you read Perforce's P4 Python help page at:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.programming.html

This will give you some perspective, though it is not complete.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you know exact perforce commands that you could run in a CMD shell, you can make use of os.system('cmd '). You can also take a look at [os.popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) and [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to do the same thing.

Comment: I'd advise against recommending `os.system` or `os.popen` when the various utilities in `subprocess` will do a better job (They can be used to avoid shell-injection type attacks).

Answer (score 0):

There's p4swamp which is also a wrapper for the CLI

```
from p4swamp import p4

result = p4('sync')
print(result)
```